# Install coordinator library by command(cmd)

Tags: android, cmd, android-coordinatorlayout

I have to install/download coordinator library through commands but not succeeded.
Anyone who have idea about this.
I did some tries with commands but it show me this message

> **A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.**
>
> **You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
>     [ConstraintLayout for Android 1.0.2, Solver for ConstraintLayout 1.0.2].
>     Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and co                                      mplete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK M                                      anager.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this,hope that it works for you.

**sdkmanager** is the new way to accept licenses, android is deprecated. problem is circle CI doesn't have it added to the path by default because it may not exist yet. you have to upgrade your tools to 25.2.3 first and directly refer to sdkmanager